# Position of table columns

Tags: tables

What can I adjust so that both columns begin on the same line?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek, latin, english, french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\parbox[c]{6.75cm}
{\textbf{Niederschläge}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{Nieselregen}
\begin{itemize}
\item \SI{0.1}-\SI{0.5}{\mm} Regentropfen
\item Nebel / Niederschlag (N. fällt gleichmässig aus Stratuswolken)
\item \textit{Koaleszens}: zusammenfliessen winziger Nebeltröpfchen
\item feuchtwarme Luftmassen
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Regen}
\begin{itemize}
\item  \SI{0.5}-\SI{5}{\mm} Regentropfen
\item Kritischer Wert \SI{5}{\mm} sonst bricht Regentropfen durch Luftwiderstand
\item Cumulonimbus = Schauerregen
\item Nimbostratus = langanhaltender / gleichmässiger Landregen
\item Eisregen (unterkühlte \ce{H2O}-Tröpfchen
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}}
 &
\parbox[c]{6.75cm}
{\textbf{Niederschläge in fester Form}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{Schnee}
\begin{itemize}
\item \SI{1}-\SI{5}{\mm} (Schneekristall)
\item Schneeflocke besteht aus vielen Schneekristallen
\item Kristallform hängt von T. \ Übersättigung der Luft ab
\item Grosse Schneefälle = Aufgleitprozesse Atmsphäre 
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Schneegriesel}
\begin{itemize}
\item Körner aus Schneekristallen
\item raureifartiger Überzug
\item < \SI{1}{\mm}
\item bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Reifgraupel}
\begin{itemize}
\item weiss, undurchsichtig Eispartikel
\item $\leqq$ \SI{5}{\mm} bei T. ca. \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Frostgraupel}
\begin{itemize}
\item weisser, trüber Kern 
\item Eisschicht Überzug
\item \SI{1}-\SI{5}{\mm} bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Eiskörner}
\begin{itemize}
\item  durchsichtig gefrorene Tropfen
\item < \SI{5}{\mm} bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Eisnadeln}
\begin{itemize}
\item Kälte, windstille
\item aus klarem Himmel durch direkte Sublimation des \ce{H2O}-Dampfs
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Hagel}
\begin{itemize}
\item Eiskugeln \SI{5}-\SI{50}{\mm} selten \SI{10}{\cm}
\item Schalenaufbau durch mehrmaliges $\updownarrow$ 
\item Eisschicht Überzug
\item \SI{1}-\SI{5}{\mm} bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Loading `enumerate` **and** `enumitem` isn't recommend. Please load `hyperref` as the last package, not somewhere in between! In my point of view this is not related to `tabulary` at all

Answer (score 4):

I would like to suggest that you not use a tabular-like environment. Instead, consider using side-by-side `minipage` environments with the `[t]` ("top") alignment specifier.

[image]

```
%% Commented out the packages that aren't needed for this example
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek, latin, english, french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{stmaryrd}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage{nicefrac}
%\usepackage[all]{xy}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{tabulary}
%\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{thmtools}
%\usepackage{enumitem} 
%\usepackage{makeidx}
%\makeindex 
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{varwidth}
%\usepackage{wasysym}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{footnote}
%\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
%\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
%\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p!]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\RaggedRight
\textbf{Niederschläge}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{Nieselregen}
\begin{itemize}
\item \num{0.1}--\SI{0.5}{\mm} Regentropfen
\item Nebel\slash Niederschlag (N. fällt gleichmässig aus Stratuswolken)
\item \textit{Koaleszens}: zusammenfliessen winziger Nebeltröpfchen
\item feuchtwarme Luftmassen
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Regen}
\begin{itemize}
\item  \num{0.5}--\SI{5}{\mm} Regentropfen
\item Kritischer Wert \SI{5}{\mm} sonst bricht Regentropfen durch Luftwiderstand
\item Cumulonimbus = Schauerregen
\item Nimbostratus = langanhaltender\slash gleichmässiger Landregen
\item Eisregen (unterkühlte \ce{H2O}-Tröpfchen
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\RaggedRight
\textbf{Niederschläge in fester Form}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{Schnee}
\begin{itemize}
\item \num{1}--\SI{5}{\mm} (Schneekristall)
\item Schneeflocke besteht aus vielen Schneekristallen
\item Kristallform hängt von T.\slash Übersättigung der Luft ab
\item Grosse Schneefälle = Aufgleitprozesse Atmsphäre 
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Schneegriesel}
\begin{itemize}
\item Körner aus Schneekristallen
\item raureifartiger Überzug
\item < \SI{1}{\mm}
\item bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Reifgraupel}
\begin{itemize}
\item weiss, undurchsichtig Eispartikel
\item $\leqq$ \SI{5}{\mm} bei T. ca. \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Frostgraupel}
\begin{itemize}
\item weisser, trüber Kern 
\item Eisschicht Überzug
\item \num{1}--\SI{5}{\mm} bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Eiskörner}
\begin{itemize}
\item  durchsichtig gefrorene Tropfen
\item < \SI{5}{\mm} bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Eisnadeln}
\begin{itemize}
\item Kälte, windstille
\item aus klarem Himmel durch direkte Sublimation des \ce{H2O}-Dampfs
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Hagel}
\begin{itemize}
\item Eiskugeln \num{5}--\SI{50}{\mm}, selten \SI{10}{\cm}
\item Schalenaufbau durch mehrmaliges $\updownarrow$ 
\item Eisschicht Überzug
\item \num{1}--\SI{5}{\mm} bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: After this minipage there is always a white page. Do you know why?

Comment: What are your page size settings? I tried to create a little test document just now, and I didn't succeed in generating a blank page following the page with the `minipage` environments. Please give an example does produce this problem behavior.

Comment: If I minimize the column type p{6.75cm}  and take out a bit of the content the white page dissapears. But with all the contend and a smaller width not everything is being shown. Can I devide the table?

Comment: @weatherfox - There is no `p{6.75cm}` column type in the example I provided; did you switch to a `tabular` environment? Please be specific as to what you mean by "minimize the width of the table" and "take out a bit of the content".

Comment: I used the column type p{6cm} instead of p{6.75}. As there is now less space on one line the minipage got longer and not the whole text is visible on one page. The rest is overlapping footer.

Comment: @weatherfox - It looks like you're using the method proposed in Christian's answer, not mine. (My answer doesn't contain either a `tabular` environment or columns of type `p`.) Please advise.

Comment: @weatherfox - I've lost track of which solution method you actually use. Just in case you're using my method after all, I've modified the code -- the `minipage` environments are now encased in a `table` environment, with positioning specifier `[p!]` -- that should virtually guarantee that no blank page is generated after the page that contains the `table` environment.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a total different typesetting would be better, but I kept it here, only removing the `\parbox[c]{...}` which is rather opposing the desired effect.

Use `p{6.75cm}` as a column type, this is aligned at the top by default.

The `\hline` is just for showing the alignment

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek, latin, english, french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{6.75cm}}}
\hline
\textbf{Niederschläge}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{Nieselregen}
\begin{itemize}
\item \SI{0.1}-\SI{0.5}{\mm} Regentropfen
\item Nebel / Niederschlag (N. fällt gleichmäßig aus Stratuswolken)
\item \textit{Koaleszens}: zusammenfliessen winziger Nebeltröpfchen
\item feuchtwarme Luftmassen
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Regen}
\begin{itemize}
\item  \SI{0.5}-\SI{5}{\mm} Regentropfen
\item Kritischer Wert \SI{5}{\mm} sonst bricht Regentropfen durch Luftwiderstand
\item Cumulonimbus = Schauerregen
\item Nimbostratus = langanhaltender / gleichmässiger Landregen
\item Eisregen (unterkühlte \ce{H2O}-Tröpfchen
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
 &
%\parbox[c]{6.75cm}
\textbf{Niederschläge in fester Form}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{Schnee}
\begin{itemize}
\item \SI{1}-\SI{5}{\mm} (Schneekristall)
\item Schneeflocke besteht aus vielen Schneekristallen
\item Kristallform hängt von T. \ Übersättigung der Luft ab
\item Grosse Schneefälle = Aufgleitprozesse Atmsphäre 
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Schneegriesel}
\begin{itemize}
\item Körner aus Schneekristallen
\item raureifartiger Überzug
\item < \SI{1}{\mm}
\item bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Reifgraupel}
\begin{itemize}
\item weiss, undurchsichtig Eispartikel
\item $\leqq$ \SI{5}{\mm} bei T. ca. \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Frostgraupel}
\begin{itemize}
\item weisser, trüber Kern 
\item Eisschicht Überzug
\item \SI{1}-\SI{5}{\mm} bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Eiskörner}
\begin{itemize}
\item  durchsichtig gefrorene Tropfen
\item < \SI{5}{\mm} bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Eisnadeln}
\begin{itemize}
\item Kälte, windstille
\item aus klarem Himmel durch direkte Sublimation des \ce{H2O}-Dampfs
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Hagel}
\begin{itemize}
\item Eiskugeln \SI{5}-\SI{50}{\mm} selten \SI{10}{\cm}
\item Schalenaufbau durch mehrmaliges $\updownarrow$ 
\item Eisschicht Überzug
\item \SI{1}-\SI{5}{\mm} bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternate version with `paracol` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek, latin, english, french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx} 



\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn}
{\centering

\textbf{Niederschläge}

}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{Nieselregen}
\begin{itemize}
\item \SI{0.1}-\SI{0.5}{\mm} Regentropfen
\item Nebel / Niederschlag (N. fällt gleichmäßig aus Stratuswolken)
\item \textit{Koaleszens}: zusammenfliessen winziger Nebeltröpfchen
\item feuchtwarme Luftmassen
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Regen}
\begin{itemize}
\item  \SI{0.5}-\SI{5}{\mm} Regentropfen
\item Kritischer Wert \SI{5}{\mm} sonst bricht Regentropfen durch Luftwiderstand
\item Cumulonimbus = Schauerregen
\item Nimbostratus = langanhaltender / gleichmässiger Landregen
\item Eisregen (unterkühlte \ce{H2O}-Tröpfchen
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{leftcolumn}

\begin{rightcolumn}
{\centering

\textbf{Niederschläge in fester Form}

}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{Schnee}
\begin{itemize}
\item \SI{1}-\SI{5}{\mm} (Schneekristall)
\item Schneeflocke besteht aus vielen Schneekristallen
\item Kristallform hängt von T. \ Übersättigung der Luft ab
\item Grosse Schneefälle = Aufgleitprozesse Atmsphäre 
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Schneegriesel}
\begin{itemize}
\item Körner aus Schneekristallen
\item raureifartiger Überzug
\item < \SI{1}{\mm}
\item bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Reifgraupel}
\begin{itemize}
\item weiss, undurchsichtig Eispartikel
\item $\leqq$ \SI{5}{\mm} bei T. ca. \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Frostgraupel}
\begin{itemize}
\item weisser, trüber Kern 
\item Eisschicht Überzug
\item \SI{1}-\SI{5}{\mm} bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Eiskörner}
\begin{itemize}
\item  durchsichtig gefrorene Tropfen
\item < \SI{5}{\mm} bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Eisnadeln}
\begin{itemize}
\item Kälte, windstille
\item aus klarem Himmel durch direkte Sublimation des \ce{H2O}-Dampfs
\end{itemize}
\item \textit{Hagel}
\begin{itemize}
\item Eiskugeln \SI{5}-\SI{50}{\mm} selten \SI{10}{\cm}
\item Schalenaufbau durch mehrmaliges $\updownarrow$ 
\item Eisschicht Überzug
\item \SI{1}-\SI{5}{\mm} bei T.  $\downarrow$ \SI{0}{\celsius}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}


%\usepackage{booktabs} 
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{thmtools}
%\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{stmaryrd}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage{nicefrac}
%\usepackage[all]{xy}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{tabulary}
%\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{varwidth}
%\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{varwidth}
%\usepackage{wasysym}
%\usepackage{footnote}
%\usepackage{chemformula}
%\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

[image]

Comment: @weatherfox: That's another question which has **nothing** to to with your post here ;-)

Comment: Do you know by coincidence why there is an empty page after this minipage?

Comment: @weatherfox: Which `minipage`? None of my codes here uses `minipage`

Comment: Sorry I ment the one with (\begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{6.75cm}}}) shall I insert the code again?

Comment: @weatherfox: No-- since in my code there's no empty page after this